# why is the output undefined while calling this function?

Tags: javascript, function

```
function sayHello(){
        console.log("saying hello");
        function sayGoodnight(){
                console.log("saying goodnight");
        }
        return sayGoodnight();
}
var x =sayHello();
console.log(x);
```

the output is- 
(saying hello,
saying goodnight and 
undefined )
why is there an undefined?

Comment: `sayGoodnight` doesn't return anything

Answer (score 1):

The `sayGoodnight()` function that you have defined doesn't explicitly return a value (instead it just makes a call to write out to the console).

You could easily adjust this and include a `return` statement within your `sayGoodnight()` function as seen below to see the returned value eventually be returned from your wrapping `sayHello()` function:

```js
function sayHello() {
  console.log("saying hello");

  function sayGoodnight() {
    console.log("saying goodnight");
    return "Example Return Value!";
  }
  return sayGoodnight();
}
var x = sayHello();
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
return sayGoodnight();
```

Doesn't return anything as it just has a `console.log`. Try replacing `console.log("saying goodnight");` with `return "saying goodnight"`.

Comment: or, if you want to return a function, use: `return sayGoodnight` without `()`, this way the `x` variable will become a function which will log its message when  called eg: `x()`

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not returning any value from sayGoodnight() function, so "x" is undefined.

Comment: yes indeed. i got confused while running in node. forgot to add return instead of  console.log.

Answer (score 0):

Because sayHello() is dependent upon sayGoodnight () for the value and that function doesn't returns any value. Console.Log simply output the content on the  console stream.